# One-day-ahead prediction of S&P500 with Temporal Convolutional Networks

Tags: prediction, neural-networks

I'm trying to predict the one-day ahead movement of the S&P 500 with Temporal Convolutional Networks [1](https://github.com/locuslab/TCN) to capture some "memory".

[image: TCN architecture]

I use daily close data with the loss function $\mathrm{MSE}(f(x_0, \ldots, x_T), y_T)$ where $f(x_0, \ldots, x_T) = \hat y_T := x_{T+1}$ is the output of the neural network. I've tried countless of hyperparameters with this very rudimentary model. But almost all models that do converge close enough converge to the naive estimation of the future closing price by the last known price. I've tried adding more features like VIX and interest rates to no avail.

Otherwise I'm employing early stopping, drop out for regularization, weight normalization for normalization etc and have tried long (almost a year) and short (week) input sequences.

I realize that this is a very rudimentary model and I did not expect anything ground breaking. I want to understand why things behave like they do.

[image] [image]

---

Question:

1. Why is it that this network, with the bare minimum of information, convergs to the naive estimation of the last known price?
2. How can one make small alterations, perhaps to the loss function or somthing else so it doesn't get "stuck" converging to the naive estimator?

Comment: Not to be too flippant, but is this question in some sense similar to, "I'm walking down a street, and I don't see \$100 bills littering the ground. How can I walk down a street and find \$100 bills everywhere?"

Comment: What's a reasonable null hypothesis? What would you expect to see here?

Comment: Good question. I didn't expect much, I expected it to maybe give predictions that were good over some period but not over other periods on the testing data based on the dynamics of the training and validation datasets on which it trained. If that makes sense?

Comment: Something that would be kind of cool/interesting is if your technique always led to the forecast price being higher than the prior day's price by mean return of the S&P 500 over your training sample.

Comment: @MatthewGunn maybe one could say in a way that if the end result is the last known price then the model has overfit?

Comment: @MatthewGunn it's not visible in the above graph but the "look forward" line is the (daily) return based on the the last closing price and the predicted. It's very close to 0 but if one converts it into a yearly return it becomes more distinct and has a positive average. If that's what you mean? It could be just noise also of course.

Comment: "maybe one could say in a way that if the end result is the last known price then the model has overfit?" – No, definitely not. The model "tomorrow's closing price will be approximately today's closing price" is extremely simple and extremely well-supported by the data; that's pretty much the exact opposite of overfitting.

Comment: By the way, what makes you say that your models all converge to the naive estimation, anyway? *Every* good model is going to produce an estimate that's very close to the naive estimate. How far away from the naive estimate are your models? How far did you expect them to be and why?

Comment: To put @MatthewGunn comment in a positive way, are you doing that to learn something about neural networks or are you mostly trying to make some money of your model? For the first, this could be a good idea, although it is a topic where it will be very hard to see any nontrivial successes. The second is hopeless almost by definition.

Comment: The first of course. @quarague.

Comment: Keep pulling at this string... The fact that this converges on the naive guess and, crucially, why, might be an interesting paper

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Bob Jansen says above the last price is actually an excellent predictor, but you should do it in the return space.

[Goyal and Welch (2007)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/21/4/1455/1565737) try to do this with multiple predictors and find that nothing consistently beats the naive average historical return. It would be very interesting if your model converges to the same answer. Also why do this at a daily frequency? What happens if you do monthly?

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason why one should prefer the return space over the actual price? Don't returns inevitably remove some of the past memory when you take the quotient?

Comment: Returns are stationary while prices are not!

Comment: Might be a stupid question but why is it important that they are stationary for a model like this? The idea here was to have the temporal convolutional network decide for itself how to adress longer term memory effects.

Answer (score 4):

1. Because the last known price is an excellent predictor.
2. I would try modelling returns instead of prices. Now the model can't converge to last price.

Comment: It can still converge to a 0 return which is in some sense equivalent to the last price in price space! Or hopefully the algo converges to SLIGHTLY different from zero in that it's the average daily return in your sample.

Comment: As I read all of the comments and answers I realize maybe the last known price should be my "null hypothesis". Could it be seen as overfitting the model? Is the setting "too general" for it to stick to anything that is not the last price, even if it's a worse predictor in the end than the last price?